# Toggle SVG animation effect when click the button

Tags: html, svg

I'm a SVG beginner so please bear with me.

Basically, I wish to animate a triangle to move from top to bottom when click and move from bottom to top if click again.

My problem is now I can only move a triangle from top to bottom by clicking it. Can anyone suggest a solution to this issue? Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <polygon points="2,-5  12,6  22,-5" fill="#000">
    <animate attributeName="points" attributeType="XML"
         from="2,-5  12,6  22,-5"  to="2,0  12,11  22,0"
         begin="click" dur="0.5s"
         fill="freeze">
    </animate>
  </polygon>
</svg>
```

Or click this link: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7ha7kjw/)

Comment: You could do it with two polygons: One which moved from top to bottom and then hid itself to be replaced by another which moved from bottom to top then hid itself making the original visible. It would appear to the viewer as if there were only one polygon.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I get what you mean but I have no idea how to do the code. This is the link I did - [link](http://jsfiddle.net/aw112gt9/). I know this is wrong, can you help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a SMIL only answer. If you want IE support, add [fakeSmile](https://leunen.me/fakesmile/).

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <polygon points="2,0  12,11  22,0" fill="#000" display="none">
    <animate id="a2" attributeName="points" attributeType="XML"
         from="2,0  12,11  22,0"  to="2,-5  12,6  22,-5"
         begin="click" dur="0.5s"
         fill="freeze">
    </animate>
    <set attributeName="display" to="block" begin="a1.end" fill="freeze" />
    <set attributeName="display" to="none" begin="a2.end" fill="freeze" />
    <set attributeName="points" to="2,0  12,11  22,0" begin="a2.end" fill="freeze" />
  </polygon>
  <polygon points="2,-5  12,6  22,-5" fill="#000">
    <animate id="a1" attributeName="points" attributeType="XML"
         from="2,-5  12,6  22,-5"  to="2,0  12,11  22,0"
         begin="click" dur="0.5s"
         fill="freeze">
    </animate>
    <set attributeName="display" to="none" begin="a1.end" fill="freeze" />
    <set attributeName="points" to="2,-5  12,6  22,-5" begin="a1.end" fill="freeze" />
    <set attributeName="display" to="block" begin="a2.end" fill="freeze" />
  </polygon>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to repeat the animation, will move from bottom to top if click again. This is not working on IE.

Comment: Yes, I used FakeSmile just now. Just realized I inserted in wrong place. May I know how to repeat the animation? Sorry because I'm SVG beginner. Start learning last few days ago.

Comment: 1st click, the triangle is moving smooth. 2nd click, the triangle cannot move from bottom to top. 3rd click, the animation is back to normal. No worries, this is only small problem, I guess. Thank you so much for your answer! Sorry because I have one more question. Can I change to click on image/button instead of click on triangle?

Comment: Try on Firefox, if it works there it's a fakeSmile bug. If not are you waiting for the animation to end before the second click. If you have other questions best ask them separately.

Comment: I have checked, your method is works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

<s>I think that it's not possible with basic svg animate elements, you will need javascript.</s>

<sup>(Actually there is what R.Longson proposed in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32431156/toggle-svg-animation-effect-when-click-the-button#comment-52727903))</sup>

A dirty way could consist to add a second animate, which will make your element animate to the original step, and trigger the right `animate.beginElement()` method on click of your `<polygon>`.

But you will need to keep a reference of the current state you are in, so in the following example, I added a `big_state` property to the `polygon` object.

```js
 var poly = document.querySelector('polygon');
 poly.onclick = function() {
   var anims = this.querySelectorAll('animate');
   anims[+!!this.big_state].beginElement();
   this.big_state = !this.big_state;
 }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <script type="text/ecmascript" xlink:href="FakeSmile-master/smil.user.js" />
  <polygon points="2,-5  12,6  22,-5" fill="#000">
    <animate attributeName="points" attributeType="XML" from="2,-5  12,6  22,-5" to="2,0  12,11  22,0" begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" id="bigger" />
    <animate attributeName="points" attributeType="XML" from="2,0  12,11  22,0" to="2,-5  12,6  22,-5" begin="indefinite" dur="0.5s" fill="freeze" id="smaller" />
  </polygon>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I saw this method online but unfortunately, it is not working on IE. Am I right? Or do you have any solution for this?

Comment: I think that it's the whole SMIL animations that aren't supported by IE. (does your fiddle works there?) Your options then are CSS animations, or javascript animation to update the points at each new frame... But hum, that would be kind of off-topic for the question and I'll let you write it then...

Comment: Nope, I have to use FakeSmile-master to make it works on IE. I used javascript before SVG, but I faced many problems, e.g different devices and z-index issues (too many layers). That's why I change to use SVG instead.